# Laravel CSS not working when going to sub-links

Tags: css, layout, laravel, hyperlink, navigation

I am a beginner in laravel, and having some trouble in laravel CSS layouts.

I have multiple links in my web, for example:

```
testing.com/main
testing.com/AboutUs
testing.com/ContactUs
```

which I used a layout stored in `/layouts/main.blade.php` in the views folder.

Inside the layout, I wrote all the css link that is based on the public folder. 
For ex:

```
<link href="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

And it works fine on all the links except for the ones with sub-links, for example:

```
testing.com/main/Clients
testing.com/main/Solutions
```

The CSS seem to have dissapear when I navigate to sub-links. 
Am I not properly declaring the CSS in Laravel? The CSS works perfectly when it is not a sub-link.

Comment: Are the view files for Clients and Solutions using the same layout file?

Comment: Yes Albofish. All using the same layout file

Comment: Hmmm, could you update `/layouts/main.blade.php` and replace your CSS line with the following; `{{ HTML::style('css/styles.css'); }}` and see if that helps?

Comment: Yup it does! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Laravel helpers to add assets to your views as they generate the correct URLs. Either use `URL::asset('css/styles.css')` or `asset('css/styles.css')` if you need to get a link to an arbitrary asset. Alternatively, you can be a bit cleverer and get Laravel to do some extra hard lifting:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/site.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/site.js') }}
{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png') }}
```

These will write your HTML for you as well as generating the links to the assets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
asset('css/styles.css')
```

It's work fine with me!